# C# Add Controls To Panel In a Loop

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, addition

I wish to add a button for every line in a file to a panel.
My code so far is:

```
StreamReader menu = new StreamReader("menu.prefs");
int repetition = 0;

while(!menu.EndOfStream)
{
    Button dynamicbutton = new Button();
    dynamicbutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(menuItem_Click);
    dynamicbutton.Text = menu.ReadLine();
    dynamicbutton.Visible = true;
    dynamicbutton.Location = new Point(4+repetition*307, 4);
    dynamicbutton.Height = 44;
    dynamicbutton.Width = 203;
    dynamicbutton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(40,40,40);
    dynamicbutton.ForeColor = Color.White;
    dynamicbutton.Font = new Font("Lucida Console", 16);
    dynamicbutton.Show();
    menuPanel.Controls.Add(dynamicbutton);
    repetition++;
    MessageBox.Show(dynamicbutton.Location.ToString());
}
menu.Close();
```

The problem is that only the first control gets created.

Comment: Have u checked in debug if loop is repeated more than once and if the `menuPanel.Controls` realy contain only 1 button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code looks fine but there could be a following situations.

1.You might have only one entry in the file, so you are experiencing only One Button added to the panel.

**2.Your panel width is smaller than the sum of all the dynamic buttons width.**

I suspect no 2 is the main reason that is causing problem.

So, I recommend that you use [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx). To add a dynamic content as it automatically layout all the child controls.

Comment: I'm an idiot!!!! What the hell was I thinking!? You sir are a genius. The buttons are meant to display in a column!!!! I failed sort of epicly there.

Answer (score 3):

Each time it is generating the same name for dynamic controls. That's the reason why it is showing only the last one. It simply overwrites the previous control each time.

Comment: Yes this is correct all but the last button will not be accessible because they all have the same empty name, be sure to add an incremental suffix to each button's name.

Comment: ```rb.Name = "rb" + panPhysicians.Controls.Count;``` This piece of code is showing that the name is changed at every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = 4;
int y = 4;
foreach(PhysicianData pd in listPhysicians)
{
   x = 4;
   y = panPhysicians.Controls.Count * 30;
   RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
   rb.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(rbPhysician_CheckedChanged);
   rb.Text = pd.name;
   rb.Visible = true;
   rb.Location = new Point(x, y);
   rb.Height = 40;
   rb.Width = 200;
   rb.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
   rb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
   rb.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
   rb.Show();
   rb.Name = "rb" + panPhysicians.Controls.Count;
   panPhysicians.Controls.Add(rb);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  I modified it and used it to make a panel of radiobuttons of physicians.  I used the count of the controls on the panel as the index of the control to add to the names to make them unique

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        StreamReader menu = new StreamReader("menu.prefs");
        var str = menu.ReadToEnd();
        var items = str.Split(new string[] {"\r\n" } , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
           Button dynamicbutton = new Button();
           dynamicbutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(menuItem_Click);
           dynamicbutton.Text = item;
           dynamicbutton.Visible = true;
           dynamicbutton.Location = new Point(4+repetition*307, 4);
           dynamicbutton.Height = 44;
           dynamicbutton.Width = 203;
           dynamicbutton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(40,40,40);
           dynamicbutton.ForeColor = Color.White;
           dynamicbutton.Font = new Font("Lucida Console", 16);
           dynamicbutton.Show();
           menuPanel.Controls.Add(dynamicbutton);
           repetition++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Panel and similar controls other than the FlowLayoutPanel is when you create a control and a second one, the second is created at the same position if you are not changing it's location dynamically or setting it according to the other already added controls. Your control is there, it's in the back of the first control.

A flowLayoutPanel is better as it will add the controls next to each other as you add them while compromising more finer control at their positioning.

Answer (score -1):

I also have similar problems with panels. For what you are doing it could be useful to just add strings to a listbox rather than using labels and a panel. That should be simpler.