# Adding GUI controls dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am facing a problem adding a panel, two buttons in a scrollable (through another panel) group box. I am not good in adding UI elements without the designer, so naturally, I've got a cluttered interface that doesn't work the way intended.

Here is the code:

```
    private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, 
        System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LinksParser<Track>.Results.Foreach<Uri, Track[]>(
            new Action<Uri, Track[]>( // this is an extension method
        delegate(Uri key, Track[] value)
        {
            GroupBox GB = new GroupBox()
            {
                Text = key.AbsoluteUri,
                Size = new Size(550, value.Length * 30),
                TabIndex = 0,
                TabStop = false
            };
            flwLayout.Controls.Add(GB); // flwLayout already created by designer
            Panel GB_panel = new Panel()
            {
                Size = GB.Size,
                TabIndex = 0,
                TabStop = false,
                Location = GB.Location,
                AutoScroll = false
            };
            VScrollBar VS = new VScrollBar() { Dock = DockStyle.Right };
            VS.Scroll += (_sender, _e) => GB_panel.VerticalScroll.Value = VS.Value;
            if (LinksParser<Track>.Results[key] == null)
            {
                GB.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "No tracks were found" });
            }
            else
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < 1; ++index)
                {
                    Track track = value[index];

                    Panel panel = new Panel()
                    {
                        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        Location = new Point(GB.Bounds.X + 6,
                             GB.Bounds.Y + 15 + (40 * index)),
                        Size = new Size(525, 40),
                        TabIndex = 0,
                        TabStop = false
                    };

                    Label lblTrack;
                    Button playOnline;

                    lblTrack = new Label()
                    {
                        Text = track.Name,
                        AutoSize = true,
                        TabIndex = 0,
                        Location = new Point(panel.Bounds.X + 6, panel.Bounds.Y)
                    };

                    playOnline = new Button()
                    {
                        Text = "Play Online",
                        TabIndex = 2,
                        Size = new Size(75, 23),
                        UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
                        Location = new Point(
                            TextRenderer.MeasureText(lblTrack.Text,
                            lblTrack.Font).Width +
                            lblTrack.Bounds.X + 5, panel.Bounds.Y - 5)
                    };

                    playOnline.Click += delegate
                    {
                        track.PlayOnline();
                    };

                    panel.Controls.Add(lblTrack);
                    logger.Trace("Attached lblTrack at {0}", lblTrack.Location);
                    panel.Controls.Add(playOnline);
                    logger.Trace("Attached playOnline at {0}", playOnline.Location);

                    GB_panel.Controls.Add(panel);
                    logger.Trace("Attached panel at {0}", panel.Location);
                }
            }

            GB_panel.Controls.Add(VS);
            GB.Controls.Add(GB_panel);

        }));
    }
```

Here is what I get:
[image: Not so nice.]

Here is what I want:
[image: Displays all tracks found.]

Comment: Form.Controls.Add(your_controll); see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GlennFerrie: Yes, I didn't miss that. I add everything to `flwLayout` which is already added by designer.

Comment: "I've got a cluttered interface that doesn't work the way intended."  We can't know what you've intended.  Give us a screenshot of what you have, and tell us how it is wrong or somehow convey to us what you really want.

Comment: If there is a clear problem statement in your question, I don't see it. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your issue, along with a precise and complete description of what the code example in your question does, and how what it does is different from what you want, it's going to be difficult if not impossible to get an answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Well, I don't know exactly where is the problem in the code that adds gui controls, so I put the whole method.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: I added images.

Comment: Much better.  I recommend you create a **UserControl** at design-time with the Label and Button in it.  Then create instances of that at run-time and add them to a **FlowLayoutPanel** so they arrange themselves automatically.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Thanks a lot. But, where is UserControl in the toolbox ? I searched and looked for it but didn't find it.

Comment: It's not in the ToolBox.  In the **Menus**, click on `Project` --> `Add User Control` --> `Add`, then design your UserControl just like you would with a Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Idle_Mind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2330053/idle-mind), his advice about using UserControls (which I hadn't heard of until he pointed out) helped me dissect the problem into smaller parts and figured out that [the size of a panel has to absorb its controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406868/c-sharp-add-controls-to-panel-in-a-loop), so according to the answer of that question, I used a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, and all controls appeared appropriately.

Here is the final form, if anyone's interested:
[image]