# How can I make N label?

Tags: c#

This doesn't work:

```
static int N = word.Length;
int z = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <N; k++)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Name = string.Format("charLabel{0}", k);
    l.Text = "_";
    l.Height = 75;
    l.Width = 25;
    l.Location = new Point(300 + z, 10);
    this.Controls.Add(l);
    z += 10;
}
```

It only creates one and I would like to create more `Label`s, right next to the last. How can I do this?

Comment: are you sure that there are only one label and not N but at same position?

Comment: Is the loop running more than once as expected?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: My first label get hided. :/

Comment: Use the debugger to see how many controls are in this.Controls, and if the location is as you expect. If you still do not know what is wrong, add that information to your post.

Comment: Consider boxing the values. 99% that it will help.

Comment: I targetting Winforms

Comment: @m.rogalski What value do you think should be boxed, and how in the world would that change anything?

Comment: I'm with servy, @m.rogalski, how would boxing help at all?  Seems totally irrelevant.

Comment: why is N static???

Comment: Value of `k` is irrelevant because it is then concatenated into a string. But idk if this will be the same with `z`.

Comment: @TaW, to annoy people who know C# ;) .. or maybe it's set without instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Add Controls To Panel In a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406868/c-sharp-add-controls-to-panel-in-a-loop)

Comment: Try to set `Label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`. @TaW might be right that all labels are sitting on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a larger number than 10 in the line `z += 10;` you will see the result because it needs more space to show your content. But if you set the [`AutoSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property like below you will get your desired result also:

```
l.AutoSize = true;
```

By setting this property the control is automatically resized to display its entire contents.

Also this is worth to mention that this property is true by default when added to a form using the designer but not when instantiated from code. Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false.

Comment: Good catch: *"When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false"* from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign only one character to the text property of your labels and don't change vertical margin of your labels, the labels are superpositioned.

You should change the code like this :

```
static int N = word.Length;
int z = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <N; k++)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Name = string.Format("charLabel{0}", k);
    l.Text = "_";
    l.Height = 75;
    l.Width = 25;
    l.Location = new Point(300, 10 + z);
    this.Controls.Add(l);
    z += 50;
}
```